# Electron: How to do force reload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

The default `Menu` of Electron has two types of reloading or refreshing window

- Reload (Ctrl + R)
- Force Reload (Ctrl + Shift + R)

I created a custom menu, and create the same functionality as the first one.

```
label: 'Reload Window',
  accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+R", 
  click: () => {
     mainWindow.reload();
}}
```

the code to reload the window is simply `mainWindow.reload();`, but how about the `Force Reload`? I tried adding some `CSS` and `JS` then try my newly created reload Menu but it just refreshes the window, `CSS` and `JS` don't make any changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use [reloadIgnoringCache](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsreloadignoringcache) on the `webContents`

So something like `mainWindow.webContents.reloadIgnoringCache()`

Comment: not worked in my case i tried "reload" method as well